Getting value of an object while passing the object name and key as parameter during runtime
I wish to get the value of Object, by passing the object and key as a parameter during runtime.
Login.page.ts

export const loginPage = {
username= '#userid',
Passwd='#passwd',
login='#login'
}


Login.feature
Given when I click on "loginPage.login" button.

StepDef
given("when I click on {string} button", function (locator: string){
Console.log(locator)
});

Output
undefined
If I am hardcode as console.log(loginPage.login)
Then I am getting the value as
#login
Anyone could you please help as I am new to this.
Appreciate your support in advance.

Are you just asking how to get a property from an object by it's name? That's just const prop = 'a'; myObject[a]. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name. If not, please provide [edit] your question to include a minimal example that we can run ourselves that shows the problem.

Hi @AlexWayne, thanks for the update. I need to pass the object name and key as dynamic during runtime.

Getpropery("object.key")

You cannot reference a local variable dynamically by it's name as a string. It's not possible. It's hard to advise more without a minimal example that shows how your variables are declared in and in which files. There may be a way to do this, but we need more info here. Also what library are you using that provides the Given api. Make sure to add that as a tag so people can understand how that works.

We definitely need a [mre] or we're stuck.
